# 1px by 1px inline-block div, unwanted spacing

Tags: html, css

**So, I'm generating hundreds and hundreds of seperate divs, all that are styled with:**

```
.box {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 0;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-size: 1px;
}
```

However, I get a strange issue I can't seem to fix. As there are hundreds of these divs, they wrap onto a new line (which I want to happen), however it leaves a big gap before creating the new line.

[image]

Visit https://jsbin.com/rofihu/1 to see the issue yourself, resize your browser to get the divs to wrap.

If I change the width and height of these divs to something bigger like 50x50, this problem disappears.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just tried line-height: 1px?

Comment: Can you add a Fiddle?

Comment: `line-height: 1px` doesn't work. I'll upload a picture now.

Comment: Added JS Bin, https://jsbin.com/rofihu/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put   `line-height: 0px;` in your container and not in .box

if you have no container, use

```
body {
  line-height: 0px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ahsv5mxb/

Answer (score 1):

Add `line-height:1px;` to your `.container` element.
The line height within the box doesn't matter, but the parent sets the distance between lines of text (think of it like a paragraph with a span; if you reduce the size of the span text, it doesn't affect the distance between the lines in the paragraph.)

```js
boxesToCreate = 0;
boxesMarkup = '';
viewportW = window.innerWidth;
viewportH = window.innerHeight;

function createBoxes(num) {
  boxesToCreate = num;
  if (boxesToCreate >= 1) {
    boxesToCreate -= 1;
    boxesMarkup += '<div class="box"></div>';
    createBoxes(boxesToCreate);
  } else {
    $('.container').append(boxesMarkup);
    colourBoxes();
  }
}

function colourBoxes() {
  $('.box').each(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16));
  });
}

createBoxes(200);
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1px;
}
.box {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 1px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-size: 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Coloured Boxes</title>

  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `float:left;` instead of `display:inline-block;`

```
.box {
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #000;
    float: left;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: With .box {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #000;
  float:left;
  vertical-align: top;
} 
it works great

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a margin or padding issue?

If you "inspect" the element, what are the "box properties"?

Or maybe you have some content (even only spaces) inside the div, which might trigger this behavior

Comment: I'm using `normalize.css`, so no properties at all are on `.box`.

Comment: Can you put an extract of your HTML code and CSS into a [JavaScript/CSS/HTML](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298711/javascript-snippet-but-i-use-it-for-html-and-css-as-well) snippet?

Comment: Can you add a fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

```
.box { 
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #000;
    float: left;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Some explanation would help to make this a better answer.